# Error 1004 when using PasteSpecial with Transpose

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with the macro I wrote (see below). Basically, what it does is sort data, copy it to a new sheet and perform a few operations on the data, such as deleting columns and transposing parts of the data. Finally it saves the modified data to .txt-files and continues the loop.

When I run the code step by step in the VBA editor using F8, it usually goes well. However, when I run the code from the "Macros" menu, I always get "error 1004" at the part of the code mentioned in the list below. I tried the following to resolve the issue:

- Assign the code to a button instead of running it from the "Macros" menu -> no success
- get ideas from related posts on stackoverflow -> no success
- rephrase the `S.Range("G1").PasteSpecial _` statement as a `S.Range(Cells(X,Y)).PasteSpecial _` -> no success

Am I missing something? Or is there an easier way to transpose data than with the PasteSpecial function? I'm thankful for any sort of tips to improve the code.

Here's my code so far (never mind the German annotations):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Speicherskript_txt()

'Dimensionen
Dim FileName As String
Dim Msg As String
Dim Path As String
Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim lastrow_all As Long
Dim lastcol_all As Long
Dim lastrow_c As Long
Dim lastrow_s As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim Z As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim S As Worksheet
Dim IP As Worksheet
Dim C As Worksheet

'Debug-Feature:
On Error GoTo Errorcatch

'Definitionen & Auswahl des Ausgabeverzeichnisses
MsgBox "Morgä!" & vbNewLine & "Ausgabeverzeichnis für TXT-Dateien wählen. Merci."
Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
If dialog.Show = -1 Then

    Path = dialog.SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'vom User gewähltes Ausgabeverzeichnis
    lastrow_all = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Definiert letzte Zeile mit Eintrag
    lastcol_all = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Definiert letzte Spalte mit Eintrag
    Set S = Worksheets("speicherblatt")
    Set IP = Worksheets("inputs")
    Set C = Worksheets("code")


    'Vorgängiges Sortieren, sodass die Datenreihenfolge immer stimmt.
    IP.Range(IP.Cells(1, 1), IP.Cells(lastrow_all, lastcol_all)).Sort _
        Key1:=IP.Range(IP.Cells(2, 3), IP.Cells(lastrow_all, lastcol_all)), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes
    IP.Range(IP.Cells(1, 1), IP.Cells(lastrow_all, lastcol_all)).Sort _
        Key1:=IP.Range(IP.Cells(2, 9), IP.Cells(lastrow_all, lastcol_all)), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes


    'Loop-Vorbereitungen
    IP.Range("I1:I" & lastrow_all).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=C.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    lastrow_c = C.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Z = lastrow_c - 1

    'Pop-up Abfragen von Excel unterbinden
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    'LOOOOOOP zum Schreiben der Einzeldateien
    For j = 1 To Z
        x = C.Cells(j + 1, "A").Value 'Filterkondition pro Loop
            'Filtern und kopieren:
            IP.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
            IP.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 9, x 'Filtert die neunte Spalte (Spalte "I") nach dem gesuchten String x
            IP.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy S.Cells(1, 1) 'Kopiert die gefilterten Zeilen und fügt sie ins Tabellenblatt "speicherblatt" ein.
            IP.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
            'Kopierte Daten bearbeiten (für Ausgabe als TXT-Datei):
            S.Range("A:K").EntireColumn.Delete 'Löscht die unnötigen Spalten
            lastrow_s = S.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Definiert die letzte gefüllte Zeile vom Speicherblatt
            'Transponierfunktionen in zwei Schritten (1. Schritt: Zeitspalte, 2. Schritt: HQ-Werte)
            S.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Copy
            S.Range("G1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=True
            S.Range("A:C").EntireColumn.Delete
            S.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow_s, 3)).Copy
            S.Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=True
            S.Range("A:C").EntireColumn.Delete 'Löscht alle unnötigen Spalten.
            'Dateien schreiben:
            FileName = x & ".txt" 'Ausgabefile wird nach jeweiligem Hierarchiecode benannt
            S.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlTextWindows 'Speichert als Windows TXT
            S.Cells.Clear 'Löscht die übertragenen Werte nach dem Speichern wieder.
    Next j

    'Pop-up Abfragen von Excel wieder erlauben
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

    MsgBox "Finito Lavoro!" & vbNewLine & "Die Ausgabedateien befinden sich im Ordner: " & Path & vbNewLine & "Excel wird nun geschlossen."

    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit

Exit Sub


Errorcatch:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: It is quite possible that the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) in `S.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Copy` do not know they are supposed to belong to **S**. Ideally more like ``S.Range(S.Cells(1, 1), S.Cells(1, 3)).Copy` or `With S <br/> .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 3)).Copy  <br/> End With`. What is a typical value for `lastrow_s` when it crashes?

Comment: @Jeeped: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried referring to the cells as you stated, but unfortunatley it hasn't resolved the issue yet. Typical values for `lastrow_s` range from 1 to 15...

Comment: In addition to Jeeped's comment, it might be simpler to just assign the value directly and transpose. It looks like you're always referencing 3 adjacent cells so `S.Range("G1:G3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(S.Range("A1:C1"))`

Comment: @MacroMan: Thanks for the neat suggestion, but your idea didn't really work. No values were transposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) It is quite possible that the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) in `S.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Copy` do not know they are supposed to belong to **S**. Ideally more like,

```
S.Range(S.Cells(1, 1), S.Cells(1, 3)).Copy
S.Range("G1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
 'or
With S
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 3)).Copy
    .Range("G1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    'alternate
    .Range("G1").Resize(3, 1) = _
        Application.Transpose(.Range("A1").Resize(1, 3).Value)
End With.
```

b) A direct value transfer can be transposed using the application object's [Transpose function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027).

```
With S
    .Range("E1").Resize(3, lastrow_s) = _
        Application.Transpose(.Range("A1").Resize(lastrow_s, 3).Value)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it finally did help! I went through the whole loop and made sure that all `S.Range(S.Cells(x, y))` statments are always referenced with the correct worksheet.
Apparently I didn't pay enough attention to this matter...